# FFMPEG Video capture with dummy silent audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am capturing video of the screen using FFmpeg and its work perfectly with or without audio.

I want to capture video with silent audio and I am using "anullsrc" filter but it's not working

> -y -rtbufsize 100M -f dshow -framerate $fps$ -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -i video="screen-capture-recorder"  -c:v libx264 -r $fps$ -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 28 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart "$output$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax is

`-y -rtbufsize 100M -f dshow -framerate $fps$ -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -c:v libx264 -r $fps$ -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 28 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart "$output$"`

Your dshow options..etc were being applied to the audio input, not video. And anullsrc is a source filter within ffmpeg, so `-f lavfi` has to be set.